# Cards animation without using z-index

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm building an animation for cards. I wonder how to have the same effect for the card animation however without animating the `z-index`. **The animation should use only `transform` and `opacity` properties.**

I want to achieve the same effect(as demonstrated below) without using `z-index` in the animation, because it will cause **painting to occur**.

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: AnimateCard 16s infinite
    cubic-bezier(0.48, 0.18, 0.35, 1.01);
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -9s;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes AnimateCard {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-72px);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  26% {
    transform: translateY(-72px);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  34% {
    transform: translateY(-36px);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(-36px);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  58% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  74% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just commented the z-index. https://jsfiddle.net/sumit_sharmaXD/ry6pqhgn/9/ Isn't the animation is same?

Comment: Almost however if you look the item 4 got into the bottom it overrides the item 1

Comment: Oh right! i just noticed

Comment: You can post your answer when it's done because I'm offering a bounty on this question, you will like it, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah It's a bit complicated when you remove the z-index property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve a more marked fading effect between 4 and 1, I've applied two changes:

- removed z-index from keyframes
- changed 100% keyframe with 83%, so that it will fade away before 100%.

Here's the full snippet:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: AnimateCard 16s infinite
    cubic-bezier(0.48, 0.18, 0.35, 1.01);
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -9s;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes AnimateCard {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-72px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  26% {
    transform: translateY(-72px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  34% {
    transform: translateY(-36px);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(-36px);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  58% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  74% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  83% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When the item is at the bottom it should still have an opacity of 1 until the other item will cover it

Comment: The keyframes should not have the z-index property

Answer (score 1):

We can clip the bottom most rectangle to height 0 as top one collapse on it:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: AnimateCard 16s infinite cubic-bezier(0.48, 0.18, 0.35, 1.01);
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -9s;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes AnimateCard {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-72px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  26% {
    transform: translateY(-72px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  34% {
    transform: translateY(-36px);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(-36px);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  58% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  74% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  76% {
    clip: rect(0px, 32px, 32px, 0px);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(32px, 32px, 32px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The keyframes should not have a z-index property

Comment: It should only have a transform and opacity property

Comment: @Vince my bad! I had to copy the original code again, then I forgot to remove z-index. :P
I'll try to find the answer with only `transform` and `opacity`.

Comment: I think without using any other properties in the animation we'll end up with answers similar to @lemon's, where the overlap will not blend well.

Comment: the real problem is that there is no possibility to indicate a 'fade-out' like animation, for this reason number 1 will always be underneath number 4 given the available css properties (except z-index)

Comment: Yes @theHutt I agree

Comment: Thanks @lemon I just realize about that man, thanks

Comment: @theHutt If using the clip property it will cause a painting to occur for the performance that's why I want only the transform and opacity on keyframes

Comment: Hey can I request you on my latest post about scaling the current carousel item to 1

Answer (score 0):

I removed **z-index** from *keyframes* and just do small changes into your existing CSS style code so check below snippet.

```css
*,::before, ::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 60px;
    width: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    animation: AnimateCard 16s infinite cubic-bezier(0.48, 0.18, 0.35, 1.01);
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: -9s;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -5s;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: -1s;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes AnimateCard {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-210px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  26% {
    transform: translateY(-140px);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  34% {
    transform: translateY(-70px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(-70px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  58% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  74% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  91% {
    transform: translateY(140px);
    opacity: 1;
  } 
  100% {
    transform: translateY(210px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost however the animation effect is not the same anymore. When each item got to the bottom we should see that It will stay then another item will cover the current item like the animation I gave I would like to remove the z index inside keyframes however the same effect for animation